# Path issue with js files

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following directory structure :

```
/script/x.js

/includes/x.txt

/1/2/index.html
```

After hooking a webpage into JQuery, if I run the following inside  of the HTML file index.html the x.txt file displays correctly...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('.footer').load('../../includes/x.txt');
    });
</script>
```

If I place the following code inside the x.js file changing the relative path to footer.txt accordingly

```
$(function(){
$('.footer').load('../includes/x.txt');
});
```

and hook the x.js file into the page with

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../script/global.js"></script>
```

it doesn't work.

This is obivously a path issue that I'm going wrong with, any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: When using the .load() function, you should give it an absolute URL or a URL relative to the root of your host.

Comment: won't starting with a slash just give you the top directory?: /includes/x.txt

Comment: For example, if the page that calls the application is in the root of your host, you'll have to do /includes/x.txt or if it's behind some subdirectories you can do /some/subdirectory/includes/x.txt

Comment: What I can't figure out is, even with my paths amended, it isn't working when I pull it in from the global.js file but is when I embed it in the <head> of the html. Exactly the same code.

Comment: I tried just the jquery in another html file and it worked so something in my existing html page is breaking it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use absolute paths. They start with `/`. That is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('.footer').load('/includes/x.txt');
    });
</script>
```

and

```
$(function(){
    $('.footer').load('/includes/x.txt');
});
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/script/global.js"></script>
```

Comment: Still, what the op is trying to do should work, and there may be a valid reason for not using absolute paths. Good suggestion though! +1

Answer (score 1):

The relative paths are always from the page you are on. Since you are trying to access a file from `includes` folder you have to go back to 2 folders and then access it.

```
$(function(){
   $('.footer').load('../../includes/footer.txt');
});
```